# Wildfly: JGRP000031: node1/trustcache: dropping unicast message to wrong destination node2/trustcache

Tags: wildfly, jgroups

I'm trying to create a cluster using standalone mode and i have followed this link http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2015 to enable clustering and its not working as expected. 
    Node1: 192.168.1.10
    Node2: 192.168.1.11

```
and i'm starting the server as below 

E:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin>standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -c standalone-full-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=node1

E:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin>standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -c standalone-full-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=node2

 and when i start Node1 i'm getting message as (it should have both node details instead of node1 details)

Received new cluster view: [node1/trustcache|0] (1) [node1/trustcache] 

From Node2 : Received new cluster view: [node2/trustcache|0] (1) [node2/trustcache]

and below is my configuration

cache-container name="trustcache" default-cache="usercache" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/test" aliases="test">
                <transport stack="tcp" lock-timeout="600000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="test" start="EAGER" batching="true" mode="ASYNC">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                </replicated-cache>
                <replicated-cache name="usercache" start="EAGER" batching="true" mode="ASYNC">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="1800000" lifespan="-1"/>
                </replicated-cache>

TCP Configuration

  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:2.0" default-stack="tcp">
            <stack name="tcp">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                <protocol type="TCPPING">
                    <property name="initial_hosts">
                        192.168.1.10[7600],192.168.1.11[7600]
                    </property>
                    <property name="num_initial_members">
                        3
                    </property>
                    <property name="port_range">
                        0
                    </property>
                    <property name="timeout">
                        2000
                    </property>
                </protocol>
                <protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>
                <protocol type="MERGE2"/>
                <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
                <protocol type="RSVP"/>
            </stack>

Error Message: 

JGRP000031: node1/trustcache: dropping unicast message to wrong destination node2/trustcache

[org.jgroups.protocols.TCP] (Timer-5,shared=tcp) JGRP000032: null: no physical address for 606e13a9-4a44-3c71-5b55-22fca7db77f4, dropping message



 I have created the configuration as follows.

     1. Installed Apache and configured Node1 & Node2 server details
     2. Node1(192.168.1.10) and added the details in standalone-full-ha.xml
     3. Node2(192.168.1.11) and added the details in standalone-full-ha.xml
     4. Enabled both node 1 & node 2 in apache
     5. i have started both JBOSS 
     6. when i start both NOde 1 & Node 2 (two different instances) i'm not able to achieve clustering.
```

is this issue related to ports or configuration?.

Comment: The IP addresses differ, you mentioned 192.168.1.[10 11] but the jgroups config shows somewhat different.

Comment: Sorry wrongly updated above one . now updated with valid IP details.

Answer (score 0):

Using the start option "-b 0.0.0.0" might not work correct.
Try to use the real IP instead.

Comment: I'll use 192.168.1.10 & 11 while starting wildfly and then i'l check and confirm.

Comment: Thanks. after adding IP address while starting the JBOSS ,cluster is working fine. thanks again.